# Why isn't this create channel code working?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have no idea why this doesn't work, so I thought I'd ask the folks on StackOverflow!

I've tried to do. Then but that didn't work

```
msg.guild.createChannel("sale-for-" + msg.member.user.tag, "text");  
    var everyone = msg.guild.roles.find("@" + "everyone");

msg.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "sale-for-" + msg.member.user.tag).overwritePermissions(everyone, {"VIEW_CHANNEL": false});
```

I want it to create a channel that only admins can view

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest to take a look around and see how to ask a proper question, to increase the chances to gave some good answers from the community: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/tour. For example, could you please show your efforts and paste a snippet of your code?

Comment: I added my code and my attempts

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: it doesn't say.

Comment: I mean: what happens vs what you intend. For example, is the channel created at all? or do the permissions not apply?